# Underscore.js template not working with json

Tags: javascript, php, json, underscore.js

Good day!
I have php code

```
  $arr = array("title"=>"test Title", "body"=>"151200");
  echo json_encode($arr);
```

Output data:

> {"title":"test Title","body":"151200"}

When i try to use this output like json in underscore I will return error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: title is not defined
```

JS CODE:

```
var template = $("#modalTpl").html();
console.log(JSON.stringify($.parseJSON(data)));
var parsedTemplate = _.template(template);
console.log(parsedTemplate(data));
```

But when I try to use this code. it works

```
 var template = $("#modalTpl").html();
 console.log(JSON.stringify($.parseJSON(data)));
 var parsedTemplate = _.template(template);
 console.log(parsedTemplate({title:"tTitle",body:"bodyText"}));
```

How to use Php json in underscore?

Answer (score 1):

Just take a look at the line

```
console.log(JSON.stringify($.parseJSON(data)));
```

$.parseJSON() takes a *string* as input and since it apparently didn't complain about the parameter passed to it (or did it?), `data` seems to hold a string ->
try:

```
console.log(parsedTemplate($.parseJSON(data)));
```